# Saving objects in files produces error: "FileOutputStream cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, file, serialization, object

I'm trying to save an object, I googled the HowTo and got a tutorial on this issue. However since I never worked before with this I'm experiencing problems I can't resolve.

So I have a huge class `Course` (contains all sort of things, variables, collectors...) which I'm trying to save in a file.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
class Person implements Serializable {
... }
```

Now, I send an object to a class Save.java and try to save it :

```
class Save {

    protected void saveCourse (Course course) {

        FileOutputStream courseFile = new FileOutputStream("course.data");

        ObjectOutputStream courseObj = new ObjectOutputStream(courseFile);

        courseObj.writeObject(course);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it FileOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream "cannot be resolved to a type". Aren't they suppose to be predefined. How can I fix this

Tutorial where I got this can be found [here](http://www.java-tips.org/blog/java-se/saving-objects-to-file.html#more-82).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to import [`FileOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).

Since they are both in the `java.io` package, that means that you'll need to add this to the top of your file (under the `package` declaration, if you have one):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
```

Also be careful about choosing your Java tutorials: there are **lots** of **bad** tutorials out there. The [official Java tutorials from Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are pretty good (at least they are *much* better than most other stuff out there) and should cover everything you need for quite some time.

For example there's a [nice tutorial about using `ObjectOutputStream` and related classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html).

More details about [packages and importing can be found in this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: I did and it worked. At least one part of it did. Now I'm getting "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException" error. How could I throw an exception to handle such error in my example?

Comment: Surprise! There's [a tutorial on exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)!

Comment: Ok, so I managed to work everything out. It works, however, I'm getting a warning in eclipse "The serializable class Course does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long" when declaring Course class. I've searched for this but couldn't fin a clear answer. Would you happen know what does this mean?

Comment: Googling for `serialVersionUID` shows this as one of the first hits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid

Answer (score 0):

To handle exceptions, normally put your code in a try-catch block